# App sudden crash loading url

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have the following function to load data. The function worked just fine till a couple of days ago. The app crashes trying to load any url, see code below and screenshot. Coding ios/swift just a few days a year, it pretty hard to figure out what's wrong...

[image]

```
class func loadDataFromURL(_ url: URL, completion:@escaping (_ data: Data?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
let session = URLSession.shared

// Use NSURLSession to get data from an NSURL
let loadDataTask = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if let responseError = error {
    completion(nil, responseError)
  } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
    if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
      let statusError = NSError(domain:"com.xyz", code:httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP status code has unexpected value."])
      completion(nil, statusError)
    } else {
      completion(data, nil)
    }
  }
} as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)

loadDataTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: Signature of `completionHandler` of `dataTask` is changed in Swift 3 so called it like this way.  `let loadDataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in {

}` No need to add `as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)` at the end

Comment: Do you know *where* it crashes? If not, place some breakpoints and/or print statements after each line to find out. That brings us closer to *why* it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code with latest Swift 3.0 syntax it works on Xcode 8.2:-

```
func loadDataFromURL(_ url: URL, completion:@escaping (_ data: Data?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        let session = URLSession.shared

        // Use NSURLSession to get data from an NSURL

        let loadDataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let responseError = error {
                completion(nil, responseError as NSError?)
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                    let statusError = NSError(domain:"com.xyz", code:httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP status code has unexpected value."])
                    completion(nil, statusError)
                } else {
                    completion(data, nil)
                }
            }
        }
        loadDataTask.resume()

    }
```